# Resize header image for mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I have been trying to set a header image for my WordPress blog but I can't get it to work properly for small screens as the image gets smaller.

Also, the image goes down when you click the menu on the mobile version.

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" style="background-image: url(<?php header_image(); ?>);background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain; background-position:center;">

.site-branding {
      padding: 85px 0;
    }

header.site-header{
        margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
```

Here's the blog for reference: http://semdesculpas.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the background for `site-branding`.

```
    <div class="site-branding  row text-center" style="background-image: url(http://semdesculpas.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/cropped-cropped-Untitled-1-1-1-2.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center; margin-top: 20px">
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you but it still looks very small.

Comment: It's small because of your image. Don't you know that?

Comment: You're right. I was able to make it look better. Thank you!